# Java Selector Stuck on select() after accepting a connection

Tags: java, sockets, networking, channel

I am currently working on a homework assignment where I have to create a server that accepts connections using Java Selector and communicates over socket channels. Clients connect to the Server using their own socket channel, the server accepts the connection, sets the new socket channel to OP_READ and waits for information to read. Below is the run method for the server and the accept and read methods for the server.

```
//TODO: Figure out why the data is being read over and over again
    public void run()
    {

            while(true)
            {
                try{


                // Process potential change requests
                processChangeRequests();    
                //select all the things! returns the amount of channels that are ready 

                //PPP: Select is stuck after accepted socket is changed to OP_READ -- data is not read
                this.selector.select();

                //DEBUG
                System.out.println("Selector Selected Something!");

                //get the set of keys of the channels that are ready
                Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

                while(keyIterator.hasNext()) {

                    //get the key itself
                    SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();
                    keyIterator.remove();

                    System.out.println("key: "+key.interestOps());

                    if(!key.isValid())
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    //conditions
                    if(key.isAcceptable()) {
                        // a connection was accepted by a ServerSocketChannel.
                        this.accept(key);
                    } 
                    else if (key.isReadable()) {
                        // a channel is ready for reading
                        this.readData(key);
                    } 
                    else if (key.isWritable()) {
                        // a channel is ready for writing

                        //this.fPool.submitTask(new MessageDigestProcessor(key,this.buffer.array()));
                    }


                }
                //fPool.submitTask(new MessageDigestProcessor(socket));
            }catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }

    private void accept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Accepted Connection!");
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = (ServerSocketChannel)key.channel();
        SocketChannel clientSocketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
        clientSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        clientSocketChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }

/**
     * Reads a message digest from the input stream from the socket
     * @return the message digest read from the input stream or "" if there was a problem reading
     * TODO read until there is no more data to be read?
     * TODO do not close the socket channels unless there is an exception from reading
     */
    private void readData(SelectionKey key) throws IOException
    {
        SocketChannel clientSocketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        //DEBUG
        System.out.println("Message received from: "+clientSocketChannel.socket().getInetAddress());
        //clear the buffer before reading
        this.buffer.clear();
        int numRead;
        try
        {
            numRead = clientSocketChannel.read(this.buffer);    
            //DEBUG
            System.out.println("num read: "+numRead);

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            key.cancel();
            clientSocketChannel.close();
            return;
        }

        if(numRead==-1)
        {
            key.cancel();
            key.channel().close();
            return;
        }

        //DEBUG
        try {
            System.out.println(Utility.SHA1FromBytes(this.buffer.array()));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //time for writing!
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

    }
```

The accept works just fine after I connect to the server with the client, but after the client writes data the server is blocked on the this.selector.select() so it never calls readData(). Is there something I'm missing? I followed the code through the debugger in eclipse and that was where it stopped.

EDIT: Here is the client code

```
package cs455.scaling;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

public class Client implements Runnable {

    //stores all the hash codes for all messages that are sent to the server
    private final LinkedList<String> hashCodes = new LinkedList<String>();
    private final long messageRate;
    private final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);
    private final Selector selector;
    private final InetSocketAddress serverSocketAddress;//maintain an open connection at all times, bro. Why should I shut it?
    private final List<ChangeRequest> changeRequests = new LinkedList<ChangeRequest>();
    //private final Thread senderThread;


    public Client(String ipAddress, int port, long messageRate) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        this.serverSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress),port);
        this.messageRate = messageRate;
        this.selector = Selector.open();
//      senderThread = new Thread(new MessageDigestSender(this));
//      senderThread.start();
    }

    public long getMessageRate()
    {
        return messageRate;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a message digest and sends it over the connected socket
     * TODO open new connection each time a send needs to occur?
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void sendMessageDigest() throws IOException
    {
        initConnection();
        //generate the message
        byte [] data = generateMessageDigest();
        //prepare the data
        buffer.clear();
        buffer.put(data);

        this.selector.wakeup();
    }

    /**
     * Does the actual writing of the message
     * @param SelectionKey key that represents the channel that is being written to
     */
    private void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException
    {
        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        socketChannel.write(buffer);
        System.out.println("Wrote data to Server...");
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);//not interested in writing for right now -- wait for message from the server
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try{

                //process the socket channel op changes
                processChangeRequests();

                this.selector.select();

                //get the set of keys of the channels that are ready
                Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

                while(keyIterator.hasNext()) {

                    //get the key itself
                    SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();
                    keyIterator.remove();

                    //System.out.println(key.interestOps());

                    //avoid invalid keys
                    if(!key.isValid())
                    {
                        continue;
                    }   
                    if (key.isConnectable()) {
                        this.finishConnection(key);
                    } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                        this.readData(key);
                    } else if (key.isWritable()) {
                        this.write(key);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        } 
    }

    /**
     * Method that queues up changes that need to be made to selection keys before they are processed
     * this is useful for when multiple threads need to make changes to selection keys
     * XXX: Used when the caller is NOT the selecting thread
     */
    private void processChangeRequests() throws IOException
    {
        synchronized(this.changeRequests)
        {
            Iterator<ChangeRequest> changes = this.changeRequests.iterator();
            while(changes.hasNext())
            {
                ChangeRequest changeRequest = changes.next();
                switch(changeRequest.type)
                {
                    case(ChangeRequest.CHANGE_OP):
                        changeRequest.channel.keyFor(this.selector).interestOps(changeRequest.ops);
                        break;
                    case ChangeRequest.REGISTER:
                        changeRequest.channel.register(this.selector, changeRequest.ops);
                        break;
                    }
            }
            this.changeRequests.clear();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Initialize the socket channel on the specified ip address and port
     * configure it for non-blocking
     * @param ipAddress
     * @param port
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void initConnection() throws IOException
    {
        SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        socketChannel.connect(this.serverSocketAddress);

        //a request is made because the selecting thread is not the caller of this function
        synchronized(this.changeRequests){
            this.changeRequests.add(new ChangeRequest(socketChannel, ChangeRequest.REGISTER,SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finish the connection by calling finishConnect() on the channel and then setting it to OP_WRITE
     * @param key
     */
    private void finishConnection(SelectionKey key)
    {
        // a connection was established with a remote server.
        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

        // Finish the connection. If the connection operation failed
        // this will raise an IOException.
        try {
            socketChannel.finishConnect();
            System.out.println("Finished connecting to server");
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // Cancel the channel's registration with our selector
            e.printStackTrace();
            key.cancel();
          return;
        }

        // Register an interest in writing on this channel
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
    }

    /**
     * Serves as a wrapper around the SHA1FromBytes method
     * It generates a byte array using the util.Random class and then generates a message digest from those bytes
     * If the algorithm doesn't exist then a blank string is returned
     */
    private byte [] generateMessageDigest()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        byte [] data = new byte[8192];
        random.nextBytes(data);
        String digest = "";
        try {
            digest = Utility.SHA1FromBytes(data);
            //add it to the hashCodes linkedList
            hashCodes.add(digest);
            System.out.println("Generated Digest: "+digest);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;

    }

    /**
     * Reads a message digest from the input stream from the socket
     * @return the message digest read from the input stream or "" if there was a problem reading
     * TODO read until there is no more data to be read?
     * TODO do not close the socket channels unless there is an exception from reading
     */
    private void readData(SelectionKey key) throws IOException
    {
        SocketChannel clientSocketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        //DEBUG
        System.out.println("Message received from: "+clientSocketChannel.socket().getInetAddress());
        //clear the buffer before reading
        this.buffer.clear();
        int numRead;
        try
        {
            numRead = clientSocketChannel.read(this.buffer);    
            //DEBUG
            System.out.println("num read: "+numRead);

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            //problem reading from a socket channel
            e.printStackTrace();
            key.cancel();
            clientSocketChannel.close();
            return;
        }

        this.buffer.flip();
        System.out.println("Received Message Digest: "+new String(this.buffer.array()));

        //done! open business later on!
        key.channel().close();
        key.channel().keyFor(this.selector).cancel();


    }


    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String serverHost = "";
        int serverPort = 0;
        long messageRate = 0;

        if(args.length<3)
        {
            System.err.println("Format: java cs455.scaling.Client [server-host] [server-port] [message-rate]");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //parse the arguments out
        try{

            serverHost = args[0];
            serverPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            messageRate = Long.parseLong(args[2]);

        } catch(NumberFormatException ne) {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae)
        {
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }

        //start the client
        try
        {
                Client client = new Client(serverHost,serverPort,messageRate);
                Thread t = new Thread(client);
                t.start();
                client.sendMessageDigest();

        } catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code where you are writing to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the return values of both read() and write(), so you aren't able to detect short or zero length writes, or EOS conditions when reading.

Comment: After reading the java doc I understood this more. I have the client force a write until write does not return 0. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Christian That's the wrong way to do it. If write() returns zero you should select on OP_WRITE, not just 'force a write until write doesn't return zero', which sounds like a spin loop.